# Cut a line in multiple parts delimited by patterns, read and re-write .json files

Tags: json, shell, parsing

this one's difficult and I haven't found any answers for hours, I hope you can help me. I'm not an english native speaker, I apologize in advance.

I arrived last week in a company and am working with .json files which are all listed in directories, by companies.

e.g.

```
d/Company1/comport/enregistrement_sessionhash1
                   enregistrement_sessionhash2
                   enregistrement_sessionhash3
d/Company2/comport/enregistrement_sessionhashX
d/Company3/comport/enregistrement_sessionhashY...
```

Each of them can contain [0-n] characters.

We use these files to calculate data.
The person before me didn't think about classifying them by /year/months, therefore it takes a lot of time when we do algorithms on data during a specific month, because it reads all the files inside the directory, which are being stored every 10 seconds per websitecompany and website-user user for approximately 2 years.

Sadly, we can't use systems' creation/modification time, only text informations in the .json files, since there's been a server problem and my coworkers had to paste files, resetting creation time.

Here is a template of the .json files

```
BEGIN OF FILE

    {"session":"session_hash","enregistrements":[{"session":"session_hash",[...]{"data2":"xxx"}],"timedate_saved":"27 04 2020 12:39:21"},{"session":"session_hash",[...],"timedate_saved":"17 06 2020 11:01:08"},{"data1":"session_hash"[...],{"data2":"xxx"}],"timedate_saved":"27 04 2020 18:01:14"}]}

END OF FILE
```

In a file, there can't be a different "session" value. This value is a hash, used aswell in the filename e.g. `d/Company1/comport/enregistrement_session_hash`

I would like to read the files, cut every "enregistrements" sub-arrays (starting with `[{"session"...`and ending with `"timedate_saved":"01 01 1970 00:00:00"}]}`. Doing this, i want the cutted out text to get written in files having the same filenames (session_hash), stored by company/comport/year/months/enregistrement_sessionhash, gotten by the "timedate_saved" data. And of course be able to reuse these files for further use, so having the .json parsing.

That's a lot, I hope someone has time on his hands to help me getting through it.

Comment: Use `jq` utility, great to parse json.

Comment: Took me 5 hours, but I did it. 
jq helped me so much. Massive Thank you